# Action-on-google V1 migration deadline

Tags: dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I am using "Action on Google" V1 npm package in my dialogflow nodejs fulfillment webhook. I am lost on the deprecation dates. Do I avec until October 23rd to migrate ?

Comment: Just to make sure we're clear, can you post the relevant line from your package.json file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct, you have until October 23rd 2019 to migrate from version 1 of the DialogFlow API to version 2. You can read the migration guide [here](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/v1-v2-migration-guide-fulfillment).

If you're using version 1 of the `actions-on-google` Node module, then you'll [need to upgrade from version 1 to 2 by that date also](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/v1-v2-migration-guide-fulfillment).